# Result of Core Data query does not change when using a predicate to filter

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm building a Core Data project in Objective-C. I have three tables with names: CountryArea, ChargeStation and PlugType. Those have the following relations.

CountryArea<-->>ChargeStation<<-->>PlugType

```
Data:
area1<-->>chargestation1.hasPlugType<-->type1 && -->type2
area1<-->>chargestation2.hasPlugType<-->type1 && -->type3
area1<-->>chargestation3.hasPlugType<-->type2
```

I'm fetching from table CountryArea which has a to-many relation to ChargeStation, which has a to-many relation to PlugType. I'm trying to exclude all the ChargeStations that for example contain PlugType.type == 'type2' but if they have multiple types they shouldn't be excluded with this predicate:
Only station3 should be excluded!

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(stations, $C, SUBQUERY($C.hasPlugType, $T,$T.type != %@).@count).@count > 0",@"type2"];
```

This returns the same result as if I wasn't using a predicate.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to exclude all ChargeStations which have a PlugType.type = "type", or equivalently "include only those ChargeStations where the count of (PlugTypes with type = "type2") is zero". So try:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(stations, $C, ANY $C.hasPlugType.type = %@).@count = 0",@"type2"];
```

Comment: I have tried with:

'@"SUBQUERY(stations, $C, ANY $C.hasPlugType.type == %@).@count == 0",@"type2"];'

and with:
'@"SUBQUERY(stations, $C, ANY $C.hasPlugType.type != %@).@count > 0",@"type2"];'

The first one removes all the stations of the list and the second one doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some examples of your data, including those you want excluded?  Thanks

Comment: OK.  To check, you are actually fetching CountryArea objects - so you want 'area1' included because it has chargestation1 and chargestation2.  But if it ONLY had chargestation3, it should be excluded?

Comment: I want all area1 object that have stations with a plugtype that isn't type2. But if they have type 2 and another type plug it should still be included. In the example I want station1 and station2 but not station3.

Comment: If you are fetching from the `CountryArea` table, then your predicate will only filter out `CountryArea` objects - it has no effect on the `stations` (it only uses the `stations` to determine whether to include a given CountryArea).  It's not like a SQL table.    I think you might do better to fetch ChargeStation objects (with a predicate like 'ANY hasPlugType.type != %@') then use the  relationship to CountryArea to get the associated countries.